# Detecting rollback in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net

Trying to detect a rollback condition when there are two or more statements involved. For `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` Method, The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) says

> If no statements are detected that contribute to the count, the return
>   value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

I'm inserting `-1` on purpose as an invalid entry in the referenced table having referential integrity constraints.

```
string sql = $@"
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM CustomerContact WHERE CustomerId = @Id
            INSERT INTO CustomerContact(CustomerId, ContactId) VALUES (3, -1)
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        END CATCH";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(result); // -> returns affected deleted rows but not -1
}
```

Rollback is working as expected but I'm not getting the `-1` from `ExecuteNonQuery`, instead, I get a number of affected rows from the `DELETE` operation (**the first statement**)

I did use `SqlTransaction` earlier but I'm testing out the behavior of embedded SQL based transactions.

Comment: Make a Transaction and Lock that covers both Statements, Check for rollback on the Transaction?

Comment: sorry, can you please help with a code.

Comment: For starters, do not use ExecuteNonQuery(). It only has one *very* limited return value. ExecuteScalar is the minimum to get any usefull Return value from a StoredProcedure. And at teh end of the day, a function return value is what you are after. That or checking any result property that notes "this operation was rolled back".

Comment: I suggest you just throw in the `CATCH` block to indicate an error and rollback occurred `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK; THROW;`. Also, Add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to ensure the transaction is rolled back immediately in the event of a timeout.

Comment: @DanGuzman can you please write an answer for, much appreciated. I'm new to this.

Comment: @Christopher isn't both statements are covered by the transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you just throw in the `CATCH` block to indicate an error and corresponding rollback occurred rather than try to detect the `ROLLBACK` itself.

It's a good practice to specify `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` with T-SQL transactions to ensure the transaction is rolled back immediately in the case of a timeout. This is because timeouts occur on the client side, where the API cancels the running query and prevents the CATCH block with the `ROLLBACK` from executing. The connection then gets returned to the pool with the open transaction and the locks are not yet released. Although the transaction will be eventually get rolled back when the pooled connection is reused/reset or closed, the XACT_ABORT setting will cause that to occur immediately and release resource locks.

Below is the T-SQL transaction management and structured error handling pattern I recommend for most situations. Also, note the liberal use of semi-colons to [avoid surprises](https://www.dbdelta.com/always-use-semicolon-statement-terminators/).

```
string sql = $@"
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;
        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION;
            DELETE FROM CustomerContact WHERE CustomerId = @Id;
            INSERT INTO CustomerContact(CustomerId, ContactId) VALUES (3, -1);
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            THROW;
        END CATCH";

try
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.Add("Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(result); // -> returns affected deleted rows but not -1
    }
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine('handle exception here');
}
```